# NoSql beginner dude. Data design and relationships

Tags: database, nosql

I have many doubts NoSQL concepts.

I can understand how NoSQL data store, but do not understand how to deduce the best way and how to distribute the data.

For example, a data store.
How to store the orders?
Option A:

```
customers: [customer {data1, data2,..., orders: [{data1, products [{data1, data2, quantity,...}]}]
```

Option B:

```
customer: [customer {data1, data2, Data3, ...}]
orders: [{customerId, data1, products [{data1, data2, quantity}]
```

Option C:

```
customer: [customer {data1, data2, Data3, ...}]
products [{data1, data2, ...}]
orders: [{customerId, data1, products [{productId, quantity}]}]
```

The B and C options have relations, but the A repeats much information. What is the best strategy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most nosql databases (key-value, columnar, and document; graph databases are an entirely separate beast), joins are expensive - perhaps even needing to be implemented in application code.  For this reason it's preferable to denormalize your tables, Option A preferred over Option B preferred over Option C.

Sometimes this doesn't make sense: sometimes a piece of data is large enough and repeated often enough that denormalization would use up too much disk space (which is cheap but certainly not free), sometimes you need the latest and greatest piece of data in which case denormalization may not be appropriate because an update can take a long time to propagate, and sometimes denormalization is overkill because you don't need the data very often.  In this case a few of your options are:

1. If the data is large and often repeated, or if the data needs to be as consistent as possible, or if you don't need the data very often, then use a relation - this will be more expensive than a relational join because it will probably require at least one more round-trip to the database, but if you've only got one or two relations and/or are able to do a batch lookup on most/all of the relations then the lookup cost should still be reasonable.
2. If you need the latest data and/or if the data are frequently updated then you can do something like supplement the database with a cache, e.g. [Redis](http://redis.io/).  This would look something like: when you update a denormalized relation (e.g. `products`) then you store the new data in the cache; when you retrieve a record that contains a denormalized relation (`customers`) you check to see if a newer version of the data is in the cache; after the denormalized relation is propagated to all records then the data is removed from the cache.
3. If you don't need the data very often, particularly if you're doing infrequent batch queries, then you can use a [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) query which is supported by many nosql databases, often in the form of [Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/) or [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/).  Note that if you're going to be doing a lot of this then be certain to choose a database with good support for it: offhand, [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) or [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) would be good choices, whereas some databases like [Riak](http://basho.com/products/#riak) will support MapReduce but won't have a particularly good implementation of it.